# ActiveRecord::SteatementInvaid is a regular ruby Exception?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

During tests i wanted to ensure that a certain piece of data raised the correct exception.

In the following example, the following database record:

```
INSERT INTO m01s (numerator, denominator) VALUES (1,0);
```

should raise an exception when called in the following query. So the assertion should pass.

```
assert_raise(Exception) {

    sql = "SELECT numerator/denominator as Q FROM m01s where denominator=0;"

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

}
```

Instead what i get is a complain that there is a 'non expected' exception.
Since my understanding was that all exceptions were derived from `Exception`, i'm asking if this is true or if there is a 'second' root to exceptions.

```
[Exception] exception expected, not
Class: <ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid>
Message: <"PG::DivisionByZero: ERROR:...>
```

Comment: Apparently assert_raise wants the exact class, which is fine in this case because it will make your test more robust (after changing your test appropriately, the test won't pass if there are typos in its code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's open source, have a look:

```
def assert_raises *exp
  msg = "#{exp.pop}.\n" if String === exp.last

  begin
    yield
  rescue MiniTest::Skip => e
    return e if exp.include? MiniTest::Skip
    raise e
  rescue Exception => e
    expected = exp.any? { |ex|
      if ex.instance_of? Module then
        e.kind_of? ex
      else
        e.instance_of? ex
      end
    }

    assert expected, proc {
      exception_details(e, "#{msg}#{mu_pp(exp)} exception expected, not")
    }

    return e
  end

  exp = exp.first if exp.size == 1

  flunk "#{msg}#{mu_pp(exp)} expected but nothing was raised."
end
```

The exception is being checked with `e.instance_of?(ex)`, [which will only return true on an exact match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_of-3F).

Comment: I see also a 'kind_of?' inside the method; due to my non so deep ruby understanding, i don't know exactly what does ex.instance_of? Module do. It seems that if the exception is a module, then it could even be a descendant and not the exact type....

Comment: Yup if it's a Module, I assume they are assuming it has been mixed in via `include`, so they loosen the requirement to use `kind_of?` instead of `instance_of?`.